# Parse iOS SDK PFLoginViewController Facebook Segue

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

Im having problem to login with Facebook using `PFLoginViewController`.
Im using the latest Parse SDK. Running on Xcode 6.1.1. Using Interface Builder and Storyboard.

My project uses a `TabBarViewController` as default `ViewController`, after Login and Sign up users should be directed to this TabBarViewController. I could implement `[self performSegueWithIdentifier...]` using the Login and Sign Up option, but not when using Facebook button.

I press the Facebook button, Safari opens, I enter username and password the web redirects to the app again but the Facebook button doesn't stop the loading activity indicator. It doesn't perform the segue to the `TabBarViewController`.  I entered the `[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook]` in the `AppDelegate.m`

My doubt is what to change in the code and where to configure the Facebook login to perform a segue to my main `TabBarController` ? Is there anything related with the setup of view hierarchy and `rootViewController` etc... ?

Thnx and cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to preform a segue. Call the sign up/sign in view controller on your tab controller views .m file with the documentation parse provides. So essentially add this to your main tab bar controller view and as soon as it loads and there is no current user it will populate the login screen and if there is a valid user it will not populate so need need for segueing or instantiating

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

if (![PFUser currentUser]) { // No user logged in
    // Create the log in view controller
    PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
    [logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

    // Create the sign up view controller
    PFSignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[PFSignUpViewController alloc] init];
    [signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

    // Assign our sign up controller to be displayed from the login controller
    [logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController]; 

    // Present the log in view controller
    [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
}
```

Comment: https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views Is a great place to start. I love parse so if this doesn't answer your question let me know

Comment: Could you help me with PFQuery to present data in a Search Display controller ? I tried to find sample projects to search data from Parse column using the iOS Search Display controller but didn't found. Do you know any sample project available to download ? If I post my project here could you give me a help ? Thnx and Cheers mate!

Comment: @LorencoGonzaga I'm afraid it's not as easy as that because your using parse. I can't see how you have your parse.com core set up or tables or pointers and relations so it will be pretty hard. You can easily look up search controller tutorials and apply that to parse backend. Although there are some differences, it's translatable.